# Cmd Up keyboard shortcut not working in Finder

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

In the Finder, the Cmd + Up and Cmd + Down shortcuts do not work (they have no effect whatsoever).

It works properly when I create a new account.

I tried the following:

- removing `com.apple.finder.plist` and `com.apple.desktop.plist`
- emptying cache
- repairing permissions
- desactivating Quicksilver
- reinitializing shortcuts in Systems Preferences

Comment: If you found something that fixed the problem, post it as a new answer, not just an edit to the question.

Comment: Agreed with @MarkSzymanski. If you figured out the problem, post your answer below in the answer box, then mark it as the accepted answer once enough time has passed to do so. I removed the answer from your question; please repost it below as a proper answer.

Comment: I could not do it because it was the first time I posted on superuser, and you have to wait 24h before posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it:

- Activate Spaces in System Preferences
- Disable the "Switch between spaces" shortcut by setting it to "-"
- Disable Spaces if you want.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15020666